# Reading a origin URL from appsettings.json file results in bad request

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

When I use "allowedHosts": "http://localhost:9000" in my appsettings.Development.json file and then try to retrieve the value in Startup.cs, the API throws "Bad request - Invalid hostname" exception

Everything works fine when using "allowedHosts": "*" but maybe it just defaults to any origin and that's why it works.

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
    "app": {
    },
    "connectionStrings": {
        "mainDb": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MailboxVisualizer;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Debug",
            "system": "Information",
            "microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "allowedHosts": "http://localhost:9000"
}
```

Startup.cs

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins"; 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddMvcCore()
                .AddFormatterMappings()
                .AddJsonFormatters()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            var origin = Configuration.GetValue<string>("allowedHosts");
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins($"{origin}");
                    });
            });
        }
```

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I can actually see that the value is retrieved correctly from the settings file when debugging but when the application starts I get "Bad request - Invalid hostname". The expected result is to see that any origin (*) can be replaced by a specific value.

Answer (score 2):

The docs suggest that the port number should be excluded (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hostfiltering.hostfilteringoptions.allowedhosts?view=aspnetcore-2.2)), try without that, and without the protocol:

```
{
    "app": {
    },
    "connectionStrings": {
        "mainDb": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MailboxVisualizer;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Debug",
            "system": "Information",
            "microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "allowedHosts": "localhost" // "*", "*.example.com"
}
```

Comment: You are right about the port, the server is not throwing the bad request exception any more but the client can't access the server either. I'm getting "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:60618/...' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."